# How to start animation before component is removed in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I would like to know how do I trigger an animation before removing a functional React component.
I am using the npm package to manage animations via JS. So I just need to call the function. For example function animate.

```
import React from "react";

        useEffect(() => {
            function animateStart() {
                console.log('AnimateStart')
            }
        },[]);
        
export default function () {
    return(
        <div className={'component'}/>
    )
}
```

This is how I am triggering the animation when the component appears. I would like to somehow catch the removal and postpone it for the duration of the animation.
At the moment I'm calling the delete animation from the parent component. This forces me to store the animateExit function in another component. It is not comfortable :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function animateStart() {
        console.log('AnimateStart')
    }
    return () => {/* whatever you want to do, it will be called everytime when this component is unmounted*/}
},[]);
```

Comment: This option is not suitable. The animation will not appear because the component will be removed immediately. I would like to delay the removal for the duration of the animation if possible

Comment: Could you tell more detail? If the component is removed because you click a link to your another page in your app, you could think of using "useTransition". That means your next page have to add some logical to wait for the finish of the animation.